# How to fix created PDF with Asciidoctor-pdf doesn't show üöä chars

Tags: pdf, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I'm writing my documentation with asciidoctor and now I will create a pdf file with my existing adoc file, but after I used:

```
asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-pdf -b pdf documentation.adoc
```

and get my pdf I've go with firefox to the url of my documentation.pdf but my formattet code blocks in the pdf don't show üäö chars, this chars i use for inline comments. If my output file is HTML i have no errors with the special chars.

My PDF file looks so:

[My pdf code block](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cOViPqM-_3b-r9wjJG81ZOzzeppOxlFo)

[My HTML code block](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15h5tjrh09LZ60vz3L4JR3iR929WywQHk)

I've try to use

```
&auml;
```

for the ä char but the pdf file shows then

```
&auml;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last issue first: HTML entities should have no spaces within them; if you need to use one to show `ä`, write it as `&auml;`.

The problem is that the font being used for source blocks does not include glyphs for some/all accented characters.

Asciidoctor-PDF is packaged with a monospace font with more glyphs (M+ 1p), but it is not used by default because there is no italics or boldface (which would provide a similar font-doesn't-have-the-feature-I-want problem).

To use it, you need to apply the `default-with-fallback-font` theme:

```
asciidoctor-pdf -a pdf-theme=default-with-fallback-font documentation.adoc
```

Note: I used the short-hand invocation to avoid line wrap. The key is to add `-a pdf-theme=default-with-fallback-font` option to your invocation.